# Partial Loading Due to " in data - Snowflake Issue

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I haven't been able to find anything that describes this issue I am having, although, I am sure many have had this problem. It may be as simple as forcing pre-processing in Python before loading the data in.

I am trying to load data from S3 into Snowflake tables. I am seeing errors such as:

- Numeric value '' is not recognized
- Timestamp '' is not recognized

In the table definitions, these columns are set to DEFAULT NULL, so if there are NULL values here it should be able to handle them. I opened the files in Python to check on these columns and sure enough some of the rows (the exact number throwing an error in Snowflake) are NaN's.

Is there a way to correct for this in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good chance you need to add something to your COPY INTO statement to get this to execute correctly.  Try this parameter in your format options:

```
NULL_IF = ('NaN')
```

If you have more than just NaN values (like actual strings of 'NULL'), then you can add those to the list in the () above.

Comment: Mike I appreciate the direction from this answer. I should have held off on this a bit because I ended up finding the solution which I will add as an answer to this thread. In short, the `NULL_IF` alteration needs to happen in the FILE FORMAT configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues loading data into tables (from any source) and are experiencing a similar issue to the one described above, such that the error is telling you `*datatype* '' is not recognized` then you will need to follow these instructions:

- Go into the `FILE_FORMAT` you are using through the DATABASES tab
- Select the `FILE_FORMAT` and click EDIT in the tool bar
- Click on `Show SQL` on the bottom left window that appears, copy the statement
- Paste the statement into a worksheet and alter the `NULL_IF` statement as follows
- `NULL_IF = ('\\N','');`

Snowflake doesn't seem to recognize a completely empty value by default, so you need to add it as an option!